С++ и Arduino, вместо данных из Arduino на русском языке получаю разные символы. Если на английском, то все работает корректно
Есть код на Visual Studio C++ и есть код на Arduino IDE. Моя задача, на С++ через COM-порт послать сигнал на Arduino (нажатие на определенные клавиши) и получить информацию датчиков из Ардуино.
Часть данных из Ардуино на русском языке, и при использовании ReadFile() а затем cout вместо русских букв показаны знаки вопроса, повторяющие буквы Р,С,ё и другие в беспорядочном.
Я только вчерашний новичок по этой части, так что подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли способ получить русский текст из ардуино в С++?
Дополнение: плата Arduino Nano с термодатчиками.
На C++ нажатие на "g" - получение данных.

возможный дубликат: Русский язык в консоли

Нужно смотреть код, что вы конкретно пытаетесь отправлять и как пытаетесь принимать. Ну и как выводите тоже нужно смотреть. Тут просто куча мест, где может что-то пойти не так. В целом - лучше с ардуино передавать текст на английском, на русском уже выводить в десктопном приложении. Так будет немного меньше точек отказа.
